# PHP: header("Location ... suddenly stopped to work

Tags: php

I modified a very simple php page on my server:

```
<?php
   header("Location:http://www.google.com");
?>
```

and it stopped to work. I get as result a blank page (Without source in it).

I modified back to the previous url.. and it still doesn't work.

What's going on ?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot know until you get in touch with error messages.

Comment: Can you re-try with a single space between the ':' and the 'http'? I.e., like karim79 wrote it. I doubt, that it is the case, but you never know.

Comment: @Boldewyn I doubt it too. I am also surprised to find here on SO too much fortune-tellers where programmers supposed to be. "try this", "try that". Why not to read certain read error message or watch actual HTTP headers?

Comment: @Boldewyn: The space after the separating `:` after the field name is part of the field value (see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2) but generally ignored. So `Foo:bar` is interpreted the same as `Foo: bar` or `Foo:  bar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php <-- check for whitespace before this (by popular demand)
   error_reporting(E_ALL); // report all error messages
   header("Location: http://www.google.com"); // leave a space between name and value
?> <-- remove this, or check for whitespace after it
```

My thinking is, there's a renegade whitespace character after your final closing tag *or* before the opening one.

Comment: I think, too, that additional whitespace shouldn't be an error, unless it came from some previously included PHP file, which is not the case.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656744/when-not-to-close-a-php-file/, @Boldewyn - I reckon it's worth a try.

Comment: I think whitespace after the closing tag wouldn't be a problem here. Before the opening tag however, it will.

Comment: I threw that in guys. There, I think it's all covered now.

Comment: I don't need references to any questions, because I **know** how it work. there is nothing bad in spaces or whatever characters being sent **after** header.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - I didn't realise that, which is why I gave you the reference. It certainly was not to patronize you. Peace.

Comment: Indeed "removing the white space" was the solution. Error reporting was not working on that server (I guess because of php configuration). I can't believe I lost 1h on it, and this was the problem.

Comment: BOth at the beginning and at the end... But it is strange because I tested the php  code with echo "test"; and the text was correctly printed. Only the header function doesn't work if you leave space outside php tags.

Answer (score 1):

You have saved it with utf8 format. Save file as utf8 without bom or ansi, then it should work.

Comment: Oh, yes. Good idea, the infamous BOM could be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could happen if you are printing something in this page before header. Or sometimes I had the same problem when I had UTF-8 encoding for the page which has header.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where redirects seemed to suddenly stop working.
It turned out to be a newline before the `<?php` tag, which I had accidentally added in some obscure include file I was using.

One way I used to troubleshoot was through the **Network tab** in the **Google Chrome developer console**. I saw a newline there before the `200 OK`, which told me that there was something wrong with one of my files.

Answer (score 0):

I had this kind of a problem. I was using my own PHP MVC pattern. Actually there were no error, suddenly, my redirections stopped working. I read tons of document. But finally, added `ob_start();` into the index page. And it worked.

Note: you should flush buffer before redirection. Otherwise, it cannot redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very good with php yet but.

I added the Refresh thing:

```
header("Refresh: 0; http://www.google.com");
```

And now it's working, but still it would be good to know how the first problem occured.
/*spellcheck*/