# Header redirect works on local server but not on real server

Tags: php, header

This line of code works when running on my localhost (and redirects you to the `customer.php` page) but does not work when I upload my code to Go-daddy:

```
header("Refresh:0;customer.php");
```

Comment: header("location:customer.php");

Comment: if you add this line before: `error_reporting(E_ALL)` do you get an error like: _Headers already sent_?

Comment: just added the line you suggested, nothing came up.

Comment: Correction - I added the error reporting line and I do get a 'headers already sent' error.  Is there any other way to redirect to a page without using headers?

Answer (score 2):

***It needs to be:-***

```
header("location:customer.php");
```

***If it shows `headers already send` then check and remove two thing:-***

*If you have any print code (`echo` or `print()` or `print_r()`) before this redirect line then remove that code.*

*If you have any spaces or empty lines in the end of the file (before or after closing `?>`) then remove it.*

Comment: I suggest to add an uppercase and a space. `header('Location: customer.php');` [PHP: header("Location … suddenly stopped to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818516/php-headerlocation-suddenly-stopped-to-work)

Comment: Hello, Anant, just tried that, unfortunately it does not work.  Still remains stuck on the page, does not go to customer.php.

Comment: Anant, I tried your edited answer, but it still wont redirect and shows 'header already sent' errors.  Is there a simpler way to redirect pages here?

Answer (score 1):

Try `header('location: customer.php')` in youre php file. That should work to redirect to this site. Be careful with the path!

Comment: What is the difference between your and my answer? Can you please tell

Comment: I didnt saw that in the app, sry.

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
```

Here content will refer to the waiting time for redirecting the page  in seconds .